# keywords in other language

Tags: languages, greek, keywords

It's the first time I write in Latex and I have faced the following issue:
I have written an abstract in greek and in english, but when I use \begin{keywords}...\end{keywords} in the greek version doesn't show properly: It doesn't translate the word "keywords" in greek.

This is the result I have: 
[image: keywords]

I don't mind having the word in greek; It would also be ok in english as "keywords", but I don't know how to do it.

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,openright]{book}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}

\newenvironment{abstract}%
{\cleardoublepage\null \vfill\begin{center} \bfseries \abstractname    \end{center}}%
{\vfill\null}

\newcommand{\keywords}[1]{\par\noindent{\small{\bf Keywords:} #1}} 

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
    %Here I write the abstract in greek.
\end{abstract}
\begin{keywords} 
    %keywords in greek as shown in the picture
\end{keywords}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: Thank you for your answers and I'm sorry for not putting the code earlier.

Comment: Do you use babel? Please add a MWE.

Comment: Maybe someone can guess the error from what you have provided alone, but usually it is a good idea to include a full piece of code that can be compiled (i.e., not necessarily your full code, just the relevant stuff and the code that allows the script to be run, such as your packages, \begin{document} and \end{document}, etc.), as it then should be possible to spot the error much more easily.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  this is usually set up by the document class, so to be able to help, we need more information.  ideally, a small compilable example that we can cut-and-paste, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that demonstrates the problem will get the best and quickest answers.  some document classes define a `\keywordsname` with the default value, so you might try `\renewcommand{\keywordsname}` to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the idea:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,openright]{book}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newenvironment{abstract}
  {%
   \cleardoublepage
   \vspace*{\fill}
   \begin{center}\bfseries\abstractname\end{center}%
  }%
  {\vspace*{\fill}}

\newenvironment{keywords}
  {\par\noindent\small\textbf{\keywordsname:}}
  {\par}

\addto\captionsenglish{\def\keywordsname{Keywords}}
\addto\captionsgreek{\def\keywordsname{Λέξεις-κλειδιά}}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
Αυτό είναι ένα αφηρημένο
\end{abstract}
\begin{keywords}
λέξη ελληνικά \foreignlanguage{english}{Monte Carlo}
\end{keywords}

\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
\begin{abstract}
This is an abstract
\end{abstract}
\begin{keywords}
Word Greek Monte Carlo
\end{keywords}
\end{otherlanguage}

\end{document}
```

I used UTF-8 and I recommend you do too (change how your text editor saves files, of course; but it should work also with the ISO 8859-7 encoding).

Here's the page with Greek:

[image]

and here's the page with English:

[image]